# НЕ ШЬЁТ НЕ ПОРЕТ или НИ ШЬЁТ НИ ПОРЕТ?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

НЕ ШЬЁТ НЕ ПОРЕТ или НИ ШЬЁТ НИ ПОРЕТ? Не или ни? Почему?

**Не шьет не порет** — неопределенный, не мычит и не телится, уклончивый *Словарь русских синонимов. не шьёт не порет* …
dic.academic.ru›dic.nsf/dic_synonims/344102/

**Ни шьет, ни порет**.
slovari.yandex.ru›~книги/Толковый словарь Даля…ПОРОТЬ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, союз НИ...НИ... усиливает отрицание. Отрицание может быть явным (частица НЕ, слова НЕТ, НЕЛЬЗЯ).  К данному примеру тоже его можно подобрать. Например: он ничего не делает: ни шьет, ни порет. Но поскольку это все-таки уже фразеологизм с обобщенным значением "не принимает решительных действий", то запятая уже не нужна. Хотя Лопатин вслед Розенталем приводит  с глаголами только выражение ни дать на взять.

Кстати, а как во фразеологических словарях? Печатное издание у меня на работе. А на том же  сайте [Академик](http://phraseology.academic.ru/?f=0J3QuCDQvQ==&t=0J7QsdCx0Lg=&nt=180&p=2) во фразеологическом словаре Федорова 2008г приводятся наряду с "ни шьет ни порет"  - "ни охнуть ни вздохнуть", "ни проехать ни пройти". Кстати, и в других фразеологических словарях тоже с НИ. А вот запятая... Кто во что горазд. У кого есть, у кого нет. Но если следовать правилу - запятая не нужна.

Добавляю цитаты и ссылки:

**Лопатин. Справочник. Орфография Параграф 78. П.4 б)**

Примеры фразеологизмов с повторяющимся НИ…Ни…
ни бе ни ме, ни больше ни меньше, ни взад ни вперёд, ни вздумать ни взгадать, ни в мать ни в отца, ни в склад ни в лад, ни да ни нет, ни дать ни взять, ни два ни полтора, ни дна ни покрышки, ни днём ни ночью, ни душой ни телом, ни жарко ни холодно, ни жив ни мёртв, ни за что ни про что, ни кожи ни рожи, ни кола ни двора, ни конца ни края, ни к селу ни к городу, ни ложки ни плошки, ни мало ни много, ни много ни мало, ни мычит ни телится, ни нашим ни вашим, ни ответа ни привета, ни отдыху ни сроку, ни пава ни ворона, ни пройти ни проехать, ни пуха ни пера, ни рыба ни мясо, ни сват ни брат, ни свет ни заря, ни себе ни людям, ни складу ни ладу, ни слуху ни духу, ни сном ни духом, настать ни сесть, ни с того ни с сего, ни стыда ни совести, ни так ни сяк, ни там ни сям, ни то ни другое, ни то ни сё, ни тот ни этот, ни тпру ни ну, ни туда ни сюда, ни убавить ни прибавить, ни уму ни сердцу, ни уха ни рыла, ни холодно ни жарко, ни шатко ни валко; более развернутые сочетания такой же структуры: ни богу свечка ни чёрту кочерга, ни в городе Богдан ни в селе Селифан, ни в сказке сказать ни пером описать.

**Пунктуация Параграф 26
Примечание 1.**
 Не ставится запятая в цельных фразеологизированных сочетаниях с повторяющимися союзами и... и, ни... ни (они соединяют слова с противопоставляемыми значениями): и день и ночь, и стар и млад, и смех и горе, и там и сям, и то и се, и туда и сюда, ни два ни полтора, ни дать ни взять, ни сват ни брат, ни взад ни вперед, ни дна ни покрышки, ни то ни се, ни стать ни сесть, ни жив ни мертв, ни да ни нет, ни слуху ни духу, ни себе ни людям, ни рыба ни мясо, ни так ни сяк, ни пава ни ворона, ни шатко ни валко, ни тот ни этот и др.

[Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112)

**То же у Розенталя, правда, без упоминания о противопоставлении:**

1. Внутри выражений фразеологического характера с двумя повторяющимися союзами и…и, ни…ни запятая не ставится: и день и ночь; и смех и горе; и стар и млад; и так и этак; и там и сям; и туда и сюда; ни бе ни ме; ни больше ни меньше; ни брат ни сват; ни взад ни вперёд; ни да ни нет; ни дать ни взять; ни два ни полтора; ни дна ни покрышки; ни днём ни ночью; ни жив ни мёртв; ни за что ни про что; ни конца ни края; ни много ни мало; ни нашим ни вашим; ни ответа ни привета; ни пава ни ворона; ни пуха ни пера; ни рыба ни мясо; ни с того ни с сего; ни свет ни заря; ни себе ни людям; ни слуху ни духу; ни стать ни сесть; ни так ни сяк; ни то ни сё; ни тот ни другой; ни тот ни этот; ни тпру ни ну; ни туда ни сюда; ни убавить ни прибавить; ни шатко ни валко.
   [Розенталь](http://lib.rus.ec/b/118184/read)

Comment: >Но если следовать правилу - запятая не нужна.   
  
Ларf, пожалуйста, вот про правило чуть подробнее. Какое именно правило? Разве отнесение к фразеологизм (весьма, кстати, условное) уже само по себе предопределяет отсутствие запятых?

Comment: Лара, здравствуйте! По поводу инфинитива "ни охнуть ни вздохнуть", "ни проехать ни пройти" сомнений нет: однозначно НИ. К этим выражениям легко подбирается отрицание НЕЛЬЗЯ. Интересуют личные формы глагола. Обнаруживаются разночтения: и НЕ, и НИ. В Вашем примере "он ничего не делает: ни шьет, ни порет" местоимение "ничего" усиливает отрицание, выраженное глаголом с НЕ. А выражение "н. шьёт н. порет"? Усиливает? Или уточняет?

Comment: Мне кажется, что в пылу обсуждения некоторые из коллег забыли одну подсказку для "ни...ни", имеющуюся у Д.Розенталя. Он предлагает заменить ни-ни повторяющимся союзом И-И. Если такая замена возможна, то пишется НИ-Ни. В нашем случае как раз такая замена вполне возможна

Comment: Нет, Виктор, значение как раз противоположное. Замена не проходит.

Comment: Добавила в ответ.

Comment: >Добавила в ответ.
Ларf, но там же везде *противопоставляемые* значения, даже специальная оговорка на этот счет у Лопатина. Хотя я бы лично "ни мычит ни телится" тоже к противопоставляемым не отнес. А уж "ни бэ, ни мэ, ни кукареку" - те более.Но это хоть можно понять.   
А "шьет" и "порет" - просто не понимаю. В чем противопоставление? Может, мы о разных значениях слова "пороть"? Я о том действии от которого пошло "портной" и, подозреваю, даже "портЫ" (т.е. портки, штаны).

Comment: Шьет- соединяет, порет -разъединяет. Как-то так... Но о противопоставлении опять же только у Лопатина. У Розенталя - никогла не встречала.

Comment: Н-да... Ну ладно, спасибо.  Может я и правда "торможу".
Или просто не на слуху у меня эта прибаутка.

Answer (score 3):

Хороший вопрос. 
Сначала хотел написать "однозначно НИ", потом решил, что "НИ", но не все так просто, надо обосновать, в конце концов пришлось провести маленькое исследование с открытым финалом.

Сейчас могу только очень кратко. 
На мой вкус возможно и так и так, но обязательно с запятой.
Если с "НИ" - то это отрицание к "И..., И..." - "ни рыба, ни мясо", "ни мычит, ни телится" и проч. Без запятой "И... И..." может быть в сочетаниях не просто устойчивых, но и обязательно дополняющих друг друга до единого целого (и днем и ночью, и жизнь и смерть). Тем более странно было бы писать без запятой "НИ... НИ...". Недостаток тут тот, что "НИ" в роли отрицания плохо сочетается с глаголами в личных формах. Ср: "Ни пройти, ни проехать [невозможно]", при личных же формах глагола НИ смущает, но, думаю, в силу экспрессивности выражения тут НИ... НИ... возможно.

Если с НЕ, то это обычное перечисление, лишенное экспрессивности. Тут без запятой никак, единым целым сочетание является только в плане фразеологизма, само по себе (да еще с НЕ) никакое понятие эта пара на составляет.

Короче, учитывая необходимость передачи именно экспрессивности, я - за написание "Ни шьет, ни порет". Хотя вообще-то Даль - не авторитет по части орфографии.

Comment: Вот и меня смущает НИ при личных формах глагола. Суть выражения в том, что некто и не шьёт, и не порет. Отрицание действия. НЕ мычит, НЕ телится. То же самое.

Comment: А я бы и "ни мычит, ни телится" счел предпочтительным - в соответствующем контексте.  

>Суть выражения в том, что некто и не шьёт, и не порет. 

Так и у "ни рыба, ни мясо" суть в том, что некто или нечто - это и не рыба, и не мясо. Это не проходит как аргумент. А вот с личными глаголами...  Ну не знаю... Понимаю сомнения, сам о том писал, но НИ экспрессивнее, а правил запрещающих не знаю.

Comment: Да, ко всем выражениям с НИ типа "ни днём ни ночью" легко подбирается слово-отрицание, кроме выражения "ни рыба ни мясо". Разве что НИ РЫБА, НИ МЯСО НЕ УГАДЫВАЮТСЯ В ЭТОМ. Как-то так. А вот к личным глаголам ничего не подберёшь. Я прекрасно понимаю, что союз НИ-НИ призван соединять однородные члены. Но образовался этот союз всё-таки из повторения частицы НИ, которая усиливает отрицание. Спасибо Вам за ответ.