# И в горе(,) и в радости

Tags: пунктуация

Внезапно озадачился выражением "и в горе(,) и в радости" из традиционного текста обряда венчания, перекочевавшего в народ.
По идее, тут идет перечисление с союзом И, значит, должна быть запятая, но создается ощущение, что тут как раз тот случай, когда подобная запятая не ставится. Хотя я, конечно, могу ошибаться.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, действительно ли тут не ставится запятая и, если да, то почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом *и,* запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов). Такие смысловые единства образуются со словами с ассоциативными (часто антонимическими) связями: и блюда и чашки, и любовь и ненависть, ***и горе и радость***. См. Д.Э. Розенталь. Справочник-практикум. Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь вряд ли будет единый подход, запятая скорее должна идти от автора: насколько тесно он предcтавляет себе единство составляющих. Ну и от контекста, конечно.

См. похожий вопрос про "ни шьет(,) ни порет".
[НЕ ШЬЁТ НЕ ПОРЕТ или НИ ШЬЁТ НИ ПОРЕТ?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/22186)

Я бы в большинстве случаев эту запятую не ставил, но не уверен, что везде.